Inside of the devilbox container composer installation automat
Inside of the devilbox container When Composer is installing, it asks a yes/no prompt. How can I automate this process to choose yes ?
cakephp/plugin-installer contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins Do you trust "cakephp/plugin-installer" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?]
